# Minor differences in values dependent on queried area size

Tags: python, era5, cds.copernicus

I noticed that depending on the size of the queried area using CDS API (more specifically the `cdsapi` Python library), I receive slightly different values of precipitations for the same coordinates.

Let's take an example: I want to get daily precipitation of `2009-11-30` at coordinates **(9.75 lat, 122.75 lon)** local time, which makes me query for the range `2009-11-29` to `2009-11-30` and make 8 hours shift in case someone would want to reproduce it.

In `bbox = [12.50, 118.00, 7.75, 125.50]` the value at **(9.75 lat, 122.75 lon)** is `0.000308474`.

In `bbox = [10.50, 122.50, 9.50, 125.00]` the value at **(9.75 lat, 122.75 lon)** is `0.000308558`.

Both of the requests are snapped to a 0.25 grid so I would expect that there is no difference between them. Of course, we are talking about 1/1000 of a millimeter here, but it would mess with my tests for data consistency.

Do you know what can be a reason for that? Is it just caused by a common problem with float inaccuracy?

Comment: I don't think we can help, maybe a question for the API provider..  but if you're asking for the average rainfall in two different areas, is it not reasonable for it to give you two different answers?

Comment: ERA5 provides value for every point of the grid snapped to 0.25 lat and long, it is not a request for average precipition, it is a request for all of the points with precipitation values for given area. There  are two queries here in fact – first, ask for a chunk of data from the server at some part of the world (bbox) and after that – check what is the value in specific coordinates (9.75 lat, 122.75 lon), that both of the bboxes contain. It is just value array with coordinates pair contain in the bbox – in first case it will be (12.50, 118.00), (12.75, 118.00), (13.00,118) and so on.

Comment: I will edit main example a little because indeed it is not very clear, thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: If the question boils down to 'Give x requests, this third party API returns y response'  then it's not really a programming question.  Does the API give the same result if you call it directly using something like POSTMAN to construct the requests? Either way, probably best to look for a support contact on the CDS website.

Comment: Indeed, it is more a question about the way API works, thank you for your advices. For an update for people with same concern, answer from provider: "The data values in netCDF files from the CDS are 'packed' using a scale factor and an offset (with some loss of precision). These packing values will vary depending on the range of actual data values. The 2 different selected areas will very likely have different min/max values, hence different  scale factor and  offset values, and I suspect that these lead to the numerical differences you see when the data are unpacked to get the data values."

Comment: I would suggest you put this information in as an answer and accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

answer from provider: "The data values in netCDF files from the CDS are 'packed' using a scale factor and an offset (with some loss of precision). These packing values will vary depending on the range of actual data values. The 2 different selected areas will very likely have different min/max values, hence different scale factor and offset values, and I suspect that these lead to the numerical differences you see when the data are unpacked to get the data values.

Comment: this is useful - did you try the request in CDSAPI downloading the original GRIB file (instead of requesting format=NETCDF) and then extracting the point with e.g. cdo ?  Do you get the same answer then ?